# Why is one almost equivalent coding solution so much slower than the other?

Tags: time

I was solving a leetcode problem and tested two different ways.

The first is:

```
def isPowerOfFour(self, n: int) -> bool:
    if n <= 0:
        return False
    if math.log(n,4) - int(math.log(n,4)) !=0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

And the Second is:

```
def isPowerOfFour(self, n: int) -> bool:
    if n <= 0:
        return False
    nv = math.log(n,4) 
    if nv - int(nv) !=0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

The first beat 58% in time (43ms) while the latter beat only 11% in time (56ms).

Why is that? Does assignment really take more time than calculating the log twice?

Comment: I'm getting consistently faster results for the *second* function, which is what you would expect, since you aren't recalculating the expensive `math.log` operation.

Comment: maybe it's just leetcode being inaccurate? that's what i had figured would be the case but for some reason the runtime was drastically increased....